# Нужно сформировать строку из первой строки в которой перед каждым знаком "с" будет вставлена другая строка

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, строки

Есть символ С и строки S1, S2. Перед каждым входжением символа С в строку S1 нужно вставить строку S2. Как это сделать?
Допустим вставляться будет "(\/)O_O(\/)"

Comment: На этом форуме задания не выполняют вместо автора

Comment: Автор бы не просил если бы ему было просто лень
Просто у меня либо псевдографика лезет либо просто не вставляется

Answer (score 3):

Имеется несколько подходов к решению данной задачи. Но всех их можно разделить на два основных случая : это подход в духе языка C, когда вам надо создать новый символьный массив для результирующей строки, и второй подход в духе языка C++, когда вы имеете дело с объектами класса `std::string`.

**Подход в стиле языка C**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const char *s1 = "><    ><";    
    const char *s2 = "(\\/)O_O(\\/)";
    char c = '<';

    size_t n1 = std::strlen( s1 );
    size_t n2 = std::strlen( s2 );

    size_t k = 0;
    for ( const char *p = s1; ( p = std::strchr( p, c ) ) != nullptr; ++p  )
    {
        ++k;
    }


    char *result = new char[ n1 + k * n2 + 1 ];

    char *p = result;
    const char *q = s1;

    do
    {
        if ( *q == c ) 
        {
            memcpy( p, s2, n2 );
            p += n2;
        }           

        *p++ = *q;
    } while ( *q++ );


    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    delete [] result;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
><    ><
(\/)O_O(\/)
>(\/)O_O(\/)<    >(\/)O_O(\/)<
```

**Подход в стиле языка C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    std::string  s1(  "><    ><" ); 
    const char *s2 = "(\\/)O_O(\\/)";
    char c = '<';

    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;

    size_t n2 = std::strlen( s2 );

    auto k = std::count( s1.begin(), s1.end(), c );

    s1.reserve( s1.size() + k * n2 );

    for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0;
          ( pos = s1.find( c, pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
          pos += n2 + 1 )
    {
        s1.insert( pos, s2 );
    }


    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
><    ><
(\/)O_O(\/)
>(\/)O_O(\/)<    >(\/)O_O(\/)<
```

В этом случае можно менять саму исходную строку `s1`.

Answer (score 2):

Например, так :)

```
using namespace std;

string s1 = "Вот твое задание ";
string s2 = ", мля,";
char   d = ' ';

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (s1[i] == d)
        {
            s1.insert(i,s2);
            i += s2.length();
        }
    }
    cout << s1 << endl;
}
```

Comment: задачку реашет, но есть эстетический момент. Полсденее мля тащит запятую которой вроде как недолжно быть в конце предложеия.

Comment: @Alex.B :) Ну исправьте последний пробел в исходной строке на восклицательный знак :)